# Display php code in handlebar template

Tags: javascript, php, ember.js, handlebars.js

How do I display php code in handlebar template ?

example -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <span class="label label-default"> <?php echo "I am inside handlebar template" ?>  </span> 
    </script>
```

This does not produce any output ?

Are there any other alternatives ?

MORE EXPLANATION---

Actually I am embedding the handlebars template inside an index.php by using the `script type="text/x-handlebars"`. Now based on the some scenario I need to call a php library inside the handlebars template

Comment: Are you running this on a server that executes PHP?  That, and you appear to have a simple HTML tag inside a SCRIPT tag.  I don't know how that would do anything...

Comment: downvoters please mention the reason before casting your vote would be really helpful for me.

Comment: yes I have a php server on the backend and ember on the fronten. And  my usecase is to display some of the php data inside the handlebars

Comment: But it's wrapped inside a SCRIPT tag.  If there is no actual code to run, it won't do anything.  If the class in question is handled by Handlebars, it should still be outside the SCRIPT.

Comment: Does php code work anywhere else in that file?

Comment: Actually I am embedding the handlebars template inside an index.php by using the script tags. Now based on the some scenario I need to call a php library inside the handlebars template

Comment: the templates are generally compiled client side, so you wouldn't be calling php from the handlebars template, merely injecting text inside a script tag that ends up being a handlebar template.  It would follow the same pattern you would use for injecting any text into a script tag inside your index.php

Comment: This should work just fine, @Ajey. There are no problems in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

PHP should render a regular text (HTML) file. So there's no reason this wouldn't work perfectly fine.

Also what your doing only barely makes sense. Handlebars is meant to display variables. I'd have the server render the data to a variable, then display that with a variable name -- unless I suppose your gradually migrating PHP to client-side or something. Serving the same page with an external reference to the variable data set (an API) is also good for caching.  Just my 2 cents, don't know your situation!